# Pop up box only displaying once using cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need some assistance getting the pop up box to display only once using cookies.

I've set up the pop up box and was hoping someone could assist me with the additional cookies script to add onto my current setup.

http://jsfiddle.net/uCVw8/

```
jq(function() {

    var id;
    id = "popupSignup";
    if (jq(".popupWindow").length) {
        jq(".popupWindow").prop("id", id); 
    } else {
        jq("#aspnetForm").after('<div id="popupSignup" class="popupWindow"><a class="popupClose" href="javascript:;"></a><div class="popupDetails"></div></div><div class="backgroundPopup"></div>');

    }
    jq("#" + id + " .popupDetails").html("put html here");
    InitialisePopup(id, 99, false, true);
    ShowPopup();
    CenterPopup();

});
```

Sorry if this seems amateur as I'm still trying to get my knowledge up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`document.cookie` is a simple long string. So if you want to use cookie to control "once by user"

```
function getCookie(key) {
    // parse document.cookie
    // ...
    return val
}
function setCookie(key, val) {
    // encode val and set to document.cookie
    // ...
    return succeeded
}

$(function(){
    if (! getCookie("alreadyAlerted")) {
        alert("something");
        setCookie("alreadyAlerted", true);
    }
})
```

If you are ok to use any way other than cookie, how about window.localStorage,  window.sessionStorage or so?

Comment: what do you suggest? cookies or the method you mentioned?

Comment: I understood that the question is "the way to alert only once by using cookie". and I suggested that "if using cookie, you have to make some methods parsing and embedding value to document.cookie". I'm sorry if I misunderstood your wants...

Comment: its ok, since i'm still learning im open to suggestions on which way is recommended. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: the thing is i don't need to display an alert message is that what the last part of the script does?